# how to redirect old blog post urls when permalinks are changed

Tags: permalinks, redirect

When you have a permalink structure set to `www.example.com/post-name`

And you want it to change to `www.example.com/blog/post-name`

Is there any way to have the old format redirect to the new (ie. adding the word blog before the post name )

If not, is there any permalink structure I can change to which would mean that URL'S are not taken up by blog posts , and wordpress will automatically redirect them.

I have tried a few experiments , i.e using /%category%/%post-name% but they are not redirecting when you go to the url without the category (404)

Comment: Not what you asked for, in this post it removes slug of custom post type from permalink (something like what you asked for). http://maltya.com/remove-custom-post-type-slug-pernalink/

Comment: I am asking if there is a way to change the permalinks for blog posts by adding the word "blog" before the post-name, and still have word press redirect instead of generating a 404 when the blog url without the word "blog" is visited